# Excel Power View and SharePoint and filtering

Tags: filter, powerview

Sharepoint Online (O365 E3 Plan) and Excel 2013.

Hi, I created Power View in excel using data from our CRM. I exported data from our CRM, created a PowerPivot table from the data, run a few functions and from there created a Power View Sheet.
From there I was able to display the Power View sheet on SharePoint using Excel Services web part.

The challenge that I am having is I would like to automatically filter the data based on the user that is logged in. Also it is important that the user not be able to change the filters and see other users data.

Is this possible?

I have already tried using Current User Filter and passing the user information, but for the life of I can't figure out how to have the power view accept it as a filter.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPivot doesn't really support per user security.  [Tabular SSAS models do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2010/03/12/comparing-analysis-services-and-powerpivot.aspx). If you can access the data model in Excel, you can see all of the data.

As of SQL Server SP1 CU4, Power View supports [setting filters via URL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rhysschmidtke/archive/2013/12/09/add-power-view-filters-to-a-report-url.aspx). You could try to make your own solution using that, but that wouldn't be very secure (maybe if you used a webpart to display the Power View report that the user couldn't mess with the url).

If you really need dimension or cell level security, you should consider upgrading your power pivot model to a Tabular SSAS model.